# How can I set my computer for Julia multi threading?

Tags: multithreading, julia

My desktop CPU is intel i7-4770 which has 4 physical Cores and 8 logical Cores. To get the most performance, how can I start Julia with additional arguments. "julia -p 4 -t 8" is right?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are two different options.

- `-t` is for the number of threads withing a single Julia process
- `-p` is for the number of processes in a (local) Julia cluster, each of those processes can have one or many threads.

The difference between threads and multiprocessing is the patterns for parallel computing - mainly resulting from different ways how the memory is accessed by tasks. For multithreading you will use `Threads` package and for mutltiprocessing the `Distributed` package.

The examples below should clear things out.

Running 4 threads in a single process:

```
$ julia -t 4

julia> Threads.nthreads() 
4

julia> using Distributed

julia> Distributed.nworkers()
1
```

Running 4 single-threaded workers (a total of 5 `julia` processes) and checking the number of threads on the second worker:

```
$ julia -p 4

julia> using Distributed

julia> Distributed.nworkers()
4

julia> fetch(@spawnat 2 Threads.nthreads())
1
```

Running 4 multi-threaded workers (a total of 5 `julia` processes with each process having 4 threads) and checking the number of threads on the master and the second worker:

```
$ julia -p 4 -t 4

julia> using Distributed

julia> Distributed.nworkers()
4

julia> Threads.nthreads()
4

julia> fetch(@spawnat 2 Threads.nthreads())
4
```

Now regarding the performance the short answer is "it depends".
Some libraries will use the multi-threading functionality while other will mostly not.

For an example `LinearAlgebra` is by default using `BLAS` which has its own multi-threading setting:

```
$ julia -t 3

julia> using LinearAlgebra

julia> BLAS.vendor()
:openblas64

julia> BLAS.get_num_threads()
8
```

Other packages such as `DataFrames` are currently being heavily developed for multi-threading and should make a good use of the `-t` parameter.

Basically using `-t auto` which defaults to the number of logical cores could be a good setting.

When running your own algorithms you will decide whether to go for multi-threading or multi-processing. A general rule of thumb is that for numerical computation multi-threading is often easier to use but multi-processing scales butter (and using the `--machine-file` option you can have a huge distributed Julia cluster).

Comment: Hello. Where do I write the code ( $julia -p 8 ).

Comment: in a bash console (or windows command line)

Answer (score 0):

That will work, as will `julia -p 8`. However, which one gives optimal performance will likely depend on which exact algorithms and parallel processing methods your code is using. For reference, `julia -p auto` defaults to the number of logical cores, so in this case would be equivalent to `julia -p 8`. From the list of command line-arguments in the docs [1]:

```
-p, --procs {N|auto}    Integer value N launches N additional local worker processes; auto launches as many workers as the number of local CPU threads (logical cores)
```

[1] https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.6/manual/command-line-options/